# Сделать из русского текста крокозябры

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, wordpress, ruby

Ввожу данные в базу mysql wordpress через консоль на линуксе, использую руби.

При вводе в таблицу wp_terms когда вписываю тег нужно еще прописать поле slug. Если тег на английском то в slug можно ввести это же слово и тег будет работать, если тег на русском то в слуг нужно ввести это слово в таком виде %d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82, иначе не будет работать.

Как на руби трансформировать русский текст в подобный код ?

Comment: Я считаю, русскому SO необходим тэг [крокозябры]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу предупреждаю, с ruby не знаком, но вообще-то подобная запись (%d0%bf%d1%80... -- это 16-ричные коды байт русских букв в кодировке utf-8) называется *percent encoding* ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)).

Поиск в гугле

```
ruby percent encoding
```

сразу выводит на http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html где пишут про  метод `URI.escape()` с выводом в примерах очень похожим на то, что Вы спрашиваете.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'uri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> URI.unescape("%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82")
=> "привет"
irb(main):003:0> URI.escape("привет")
=> "%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82"
```